# mutt is changing the content in body

Tags: shell-script, mutt, mail-command

I have a text file with multiple lines in content . But when I am sending it in mail all the lines are coming in one line in email as part of body of mail.

But when I insert empty line in content file "testFile"  . I getting empty lines in mail which is expected, but without empty lines all lines are getting merged into single line .

I am using command in below format.

```
mutt -s "Subject Test Mail " user@example.com < testFile
```

sample testFile

```
this is line1
this is line2
this is line3
this is line4
```

Received mail as part of body

```
this is line1 this is line2 this is line3 this is line4
```

Comment: This will most probably be an issue with how the client is parsing the file, stripping out the new lines.

Comment: What client is being used? Outlook I recall likes to mangle lines like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the lines in your data file contain trailing spaces at the end of the line, the client reading program may be assuming you are using "format=flowed" mode, see [rfc2646](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2646.txt), and for example [this article](http://brianbuccola.com/line-breaks-in-mutt-and-vim/).

You can visualize such characters with `cat -vet`, and could try removing the trailing spaces or tabs with, for example,  gnu sed:

```
sed 's/[ \t]\+$//'
```

Comment: Hi ,
Thank you so much for the pointer about trailing space. I have added to empty tabs in the each line and that resolved my problem . 

Thanks,